# Access <LI> class inside Repeater

Tags: asp.net, repeater, itemtemplate

I have a Repeater that contains ItemTemplate which has `<li>'s`. I need to access this `<li>` in the RepeaterProdView__ItemDataBound event.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterProdView" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="RepeaterProdView__ItemDataBound">   
<ItemTemplate>
<li id="liProdView" class="prodviewwide" runat="server">
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:swapPicture('../images/products/<%#Eval("option1Other")%>','../images/products/<%#Eval("option1Other2")%>','masterLink')">
<img src="images/products/<%#Eval("option1Desc")%>" height="125" />
</a>
</li>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I would like to dynamically change the class

```
<li id="liProdView" class="prodviewshort" runat="server">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your `RepeaterProdView__ItemDataBound` method:

```
var liProdView = e.Item.FindControl("liProdView") as HtmlGenericControl;

if (liProdView != null)
{
    liProdView.Attributes["class"] = "prodviewshort";
}
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 3):

You can [find the control in ItemDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeateritem.findcontrol.aspx) with `e.Item.FindControl("liProdView)`.
I think its a HtmlGenericControl, but i'm not sure. It suffices if you'll cast it to a  Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlControl and set it's class-attribute:

```
liProdView.Attributes.Add("class", "yourClass");
```